# Finding similarity between datasets

Tags: algorithm, math, hash, dataset

I have data sets containing different values:

> Set1 = {X1, X2, ..., Xn}
>
> Set2 = {X1, X2, ..., Xn}
>
> ...

X values have different range (which is exactly why I can't figure out needed algorithm to solve my problem) - some are strictly [0.0 - 1.0] values, others might be in different/any range.

I need to figure out a way to "group" these Sets, or in other words - find "similarity" between two given sets.

Obviously I could simply write long chains of "IF" statements comparing each value with another and if they differ by some DELTA amount, I can indicate that two given sets are not "similar". The problem is, my sets are huge and contains dynamic data. Therefore I need a *generic* function to calculate some sort of Hash value for each set (at least that's the way I'm thinking):

> int hash1 = HashFunction(Set1)
>
> int hash2 = HashFunction(Set2)
>
> if (|hash1 - hash2| < DELTA): return "Sets are similar"

I would really appreciate any tips or ideas how to implement it.

**Update:**

Reading through comments I realized maybe I should change my question a bit as well: *What are your suggestions for a good "similarity" metric?*

By "similarity" I mean some dynamic value indicating how "close" sets' values are. For example, if I have a test set: *SetA{ 0.5, 100 }*, then *SetB{ 0.5, 100 }* should yield 1 (or some other value indicating a perfect match). At the same comparing *SetA* with *SetC { 0.1, 300 }* should return a lot lower "match" value, while *SetD { 0.45, 101 }* should return a value similar to a "perfect match". The key thing to notice here, for example values of 0.45 and 0.5 are "more similar" than values of 100 and 300 because: *|0.45 - 0.5| / max(0.45, 0.5) < |100 - 300| / max(100, 300)*.

If I simply calculate sum of value difference between 2 sets, it won't provide me any meaningful result (since two sets can contain completely different numbers (from logical point of view), yet cancel each other out giving incorrect result)

Comment: You will have to significantly refine what you mean by "similar" to get a meaningful answer.

Comment: Choice of language would affect responses, to some degree - what stack are you working with?

Comment: what are your set elements? numbers? what is your notion of similarity? E.g., is {1;2;3} closer to {1;2;4} than to {1.1;1.9;3.01}?

Comment: @JerKimball well I'm using C#, but I don't think it should matter

Comment: @rexem It might not affect the *algorithmic* approach, but would possibly affect the implementation route, especially in a "generic" sense.

Comment: @sds sets contain numbers. What constitutes to similarity is part of my question. In your example if I define "similarity" by F() = |value1-value2|/max(value1, value2), then first-second sets pair would give value of 0.25, and first-third = 0.3884, making first pair "more similar". But this "similarity" function has a lot of flaws obvious, and therefore I'm asking what kind of metric for measuring named similarities people can suggest me to use.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to know the distance between two objects. In mathematics a set together with an operation that gives a distance for the objects in the set is called a [metric space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space).

Obviously there are several possible choices for the metric. Common ones are the sum of absolute differences (distance = |x1-y1|+|x2-y2|+...) and the sum of squared differences (distance = (x1-y1)²+(x2-y2)²+...). If these metrics don't suit you, please define what you mean by "similar."

Answer (score 0):

Since your sets have the same cardinality but you do not care about the order (i.e., they are *sets*, not *vectors*), an approach I would suggest is: sort the sets and treat them as vectors.

Now the question is, which [metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space) on R<sup>2</sup> to choose.

The options are many. Basically, you can pick any metric on R and combine them coordinate-wise.

So, if you want relative differences, you can define

reldist(x,y) = abs(x-y)/max(x,y)

dist<sub>1</sub>(A,B) = sum<sub>i</sub>(reldist(a<sub>i</sub>,b<sub>i</sub>))

or

dist<sub>2</sub>(A,B)=sqrt(sum<sub>i</sub>(reldist(a<sub>i</sub>,b<sub>i</sub>)<sup>2</sup>))

Remember, A and B are sorted, so a<sub>i</sub> should match b<sub>i</sub>.